# Beginner javascript/jquery - document.write

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready, document.write

So far I only know how to write code for AFTER the html has loaded. How do I use a function like this:

```
function makeBranches(){
    document.write("<center>")
    var bq = 10;
    for (var run = 0;run<bq;run++){
        for (var length=0;length<=run;length++)
            document.write("<font color=green><b>^</b></font>");
        document.write("<br>");

    }
    document.write("</center>");
}
```

inside of $(document).ready, without it overwriting the html?

Comment: Don't use `document.write`. Use `append` or `html` and `text` functions in jQuery instead.

Answer (score 1):

`document.write` replaces your document. If you just want this code in the body of your document, simply replace `document.write` with `document.body.innerHTML += 'my code'`. I use the `+=` operator because you are appending multiple things. if you simply did `=` it would replace every time, whereas `+=` takes the current html in your body, replaces it with itself plus what you just added.

And to target another element you can do `document.querySelector(element).innerHTML;` or jquery `$(element).html();`

Comment: *"document.write replaces your document."* Only under specific circumstances, not in general.

Comment: it was my understanding that calling document.write also calls document.open which clears the document. But I never used document.write as it's not very useful in 99% of cases hah

Comment: It only calls `document.open` if `document.close` as been called. Which happens when the browser finished parsing the HTML. So if you call `document.write` beforehand, the markup will just be inserted where it was called.